# how to create curved extrude faces that works with subsurface division

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface, extrude

[image]

[image]

hi, new blender user here, atleast here is what i am trying to do, a curved faces like the pict, extrude outward and subsurface division it, even after adding bezel on last image, the top and the triangle web didnt works well and overlapping, is there other simpler method to do what i am trying to do ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topology seems to work fine:

[image]

This topology seems to work even better:

[image]

Or:

[image]

To do it, create a 8 vertex circle, put it in front of your cylinder, select your cylinder, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click on the circle and header menu > *Mesh > Knife Project*, it will cut the circle on the cylinder, then you just need to join vertices, add edge loops, etc:

[image]

Comment: yes thats what i am looking for, how do i do that, because my first step was insert faces and then bevel the vertices ( having hard time to have curved faces to extrude, so far only found that way ), how to get what you are doing if i can ask ? thank you !

Comment: great, got it, thank you again kind strangers !

Comment: I've edited, I think the second topology works better

Comment: yep, just tried the second/alt for learning purpose also, it works better and nicer. last question if it's still ok, how do i copy the extruded face into 360 literally, like 5/6 faces the fast/right way that still have same spacing range between extruded faces? with anchor point in the middle of the cylinder

Comment: you mean you want to duplicate the same extrusion all around? You can keep only several faces of the cylinder, like a slice of cylinder, and use an Array modifier with the Object Offset option enabled, put an empty at the center of the cylinder, choose it as the object of the Object Offset, rotate it. Or simply duplicate and rotate the slice of your cylinder with the rotation center at the center of the cylinder.

Comment: yeah that's it, i just need a direction on what menu/step to look for and that's correct ! thanks again mate, means a lot to me !